# Schedule a conditional job in Jenkins by excluding weekends

Tags: jenkins

How can I schedule @midnight job that should start only from Monday to Friday and not start if it was manually run in the last 24 hours?

> 0 0 * * 1-5

Is it a correct timing? And what about the manually run in the last 24h condition?

Comment: Does this jenkins job has an SCM section? Is this a MVN project ? If you use any SCM in the job worth looking into the plugin "Pre SCM BuildStep Plugin". You can write a shell script to find if the last build run was with in 24 hrs, if yes then fail the build, if not continue.

Answer (score 7):

To schedule a midnight job on weekday, the correct timing is this. Please note jenkins the `0 0 * * 1-5` format is depreciated.

```
H 0 * * 1-5
```

For the "not start if it was manually run in the last 24 hours" condition, I don't think it is possible by using above `crontab` syntax only. The first solution come to my mind is to use the programmatic way by using [Jenkins API](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-jenkins).

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking if someone knows of a plugin that has such a functionality as it is a very basic requirement, I think. I don't expect the cron expression to have the "not start if it was manually run..." logic. Thanks for the expression.